# Android / Google Play Not all devices supported

Tags: android, android-manifest, device

I recently see that about 300 devices aren't supported by my app (and about 50 of Samsung (Galaxy S– GT-I9018 / Galaxy S– GT-I9010 / etc..))

I read several times my manifest but nothing seems strange to me. Does anyone have an idea or an advice ?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gamequiz.activity"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.0.6" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true" />

   //other stuff

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set your minimum SDK to 10, which is Gingerbread, so all devices running anything below the first revision of Gingerbread will be incompatible with your device.

If your app doesn't rely on Gingerbread and above APIs, you could try lowering `android:minSdkVersion` to a lower API level

Comment: But a user can install another version of android on his device right ? How it knows that the Galaxy S– GT-I9018 (per example) runs in an android version lower than Gingerbread ?

Comment: @user2336315 Not all device receive updates, and a lot of samsung's older devices never made it past Eclair and Froyo.

Comment: Ok so I just have to set the `minSdkVersion` attribute to a lower version ?

Comment: Yeah, if you aren't using any of the new APIs